# How to integrate PayPal/Apple Pay payment module in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, applepay

I am doing R&D on How to integrate PayPal/Apple Pay payment module in iOS App.

> For example in my app i want to integrate PayPal/Apple pay for payment, then what should I do ? What are the process.

IF anyone can guide how to do it. Please suggest me the steps.
Any reference link then also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the payment solution you've  integrated. 
PayPal will support funding source of account balance or credit card/debit card/bank that is linked to the account. While unlike the PayPal wallet, there's no "balance" thing in the Apple Pay/Apple Wallet, which works purely with card tokenization (cards that you setup in your Wallet App).

In this use case, your app won't necessarily to check whether $20 is available in the wallet (either PayPal or Apple Pay), instead it will initiate the payment request, and get the response from the payment gateway to process your orders

Comment: @Florence, access this link: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/  (need to login with your LIVE PayPal account first), and create an APP there, obtain the clientID for both sandbox and LIVE environment in that page then

Comment: I had done this, but its giving me an error 

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: That's not a PayPal API response, you may add the exact exception stack in your question

Answer (score 2):

## in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [PayPalMobile initializeWithClientIdsForEnvironments:@{PayPalEnvironmentProduction : @"YOUR_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PRODUCTION",
                                                           PayPalEnvironmentSandbox : @"AeB0tbkw-z4Ys3NvxekUZxnVNk26WXRodQBETFG4x-HtQAuqBf5k4edWOn2zia_l8RWBFJGEUNSVWJWg"}];

    return YES;
}
```

## with your Controller

## in your .h File set delegate

@interface MyCart : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong, readwrite) PayPalConfiguration *payPalConfig;

## in your .m File

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSString *environment=@"sandbox";
    self.environment = environment;
    [PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:environment];


 _payPalConfig = [[PayPalConfiguration alloc] init];
    _payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;
    _payPalConfig.merchantName = @"ScanPay";
    _payPalConfig.merchantPrivacyPolicyURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/privacy-full"];
    _payPalConfig.merchantUserAgreementURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/ua/useragreement-full"];

    _payPalConfig.languageOrLocale = [NSLocale preferredLanguages][0];

    _payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption = PayPalShippingAddressOptionPayPal;


}
```

## Code with purchase button event

```
-(IBAction)btnCheckoutTapped
{
//    UIAlertView *alt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"ScanPay" message:@"Under Development" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
//    [alt show];

    NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithDouble:Price];

    // Optional: include payment details
    NSDecimalNumber *shipping = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0.00"];
    NSDecimalNumber *tax = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0.00"];
    PayPalPaymentDetails *paymentDetails = [PayPalPaymentDetails paymentDetailsWithSubtotal:subtotal
                                                                               withShipping:shipping
                                                                                    withTax:tax];
    NSDecimalNumber *total = [[subtotal decimalNumberByAdding:shipping] decimalNumberByAdding:tax];

    PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
    payment.amount = total;
    payment.currencyCode = @"USD";
    payment.shortDescription = @"You Pay";
    payment.paymentDetails = paymentDetails; // if not including payment details, then leave payment.paymentDetails as nil
    if (!payment.processable) {
        // This particular payment will always be processable. If, for
        // example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was
        // empty, this payment wouldn't be processable, and you'd want
        // to handle that here.
    }
    // Update payPalConfig re accepting credit cards.
    self.payPalConfig.acceptCreditCards = YES;

    PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment
                                                                                                configuration:self.payPalConfig
                                                                                                     delegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

## PayPalPaymentDelegate methods

```
- (void)payPalPaymentViewController:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController didCompletePayment:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Success!");
    [self ErrorWithString:@"PayPal Payment Success!"];



    self.resultText = [completedPayment description];
    //[self showSuccess];

    [self sendCompletedPaymentToServer:completedPayment]; // Payment was processed successfully; send to server for verification and fulfillment
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    ReceiptScreen *obj=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ReceiptScreen"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

}

- (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController {
    NSLog(@"PayPal Payment Canceled");
    self.resultText = nil;
  //  self.successView.hidden = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Proof of payment validation

- (void)sendCompletedPaymentToServer:(PayPalPayment *)completedPayment {
    // TODO: Send completedPayment.confirmation to server
    NSLog(@"Here is your proof of payment:\n\n%@\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.", completedPayment.confirmation);
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Chirag ...I need your help...facing some issues in paypal integration in ios...

Comment: yes sure sorry for late replay can you describe your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

1. PayPal - Here is complete PayPal sample code suggested by `https://developer.paypal.com`, [PayPal Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/) and [Sample code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK)
2. Apple Pay - You can check it apple's [demo code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Emporium/Introduction/Intro.html)

I hope you are looking for it. :)